# Append list to list, overwrite values

Tags: python, list, append, overwrite

I want append to list1, another list2, so modify the list2 and another time append to list1, but the values of list1 are overwrite.

I used `[:]` with the append and works ok:

```
list1=[1,2]
list2=[]

list2.append(list1[:])

list1[0]=20

print list1, list2 # [20, 2] [[1, 2]]
```

But the problem is when the list has another list inside

```
list1=[[2,1],[2]] 
list2=[]

list2.append(list1[:])

print list1, list2  #[[2, 1], [2]] [[[2, 1], [2]]]

list1[0][0]=25

list2.append(list1)

print list1, list2  #[[25, 1], [2]] [[[**25**, 1], [2]], [[25, 1], [2]]]
```

I want to be that the last print was `[[25, 1], [2]] [[[2, 1], [2]], [[25, 1], [2]]]`

Comment: The issue here is that lists are mutable - you are changing the value of the list, and the list inside your other list is simply a pointer to it, so that changes too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're asking is:

```
from copy import deepcopy
list1.append(deepcopy(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you make a new object with the exact same contents as the list pointed to by **list1** and make **lisT1** point to this copy. This way, if you modify **list1** (or what **list1** points to), **lisT1** (or what **lisT1** points to) will remain unchanged.
for example :

```
>>> list1=[[2,1],[2]]
>>> list2=[]
>>> lisT1 = [[2,1],[2]]
>>> list2.append(lisT1[:])
>>> print (list1, list2)
[[2, 1], [2]] [[[2, 1], [2]]]
>>> list1[0][0]=25
>>> list2.append(list1)
>>> print (list1, list2)
[[25, 1], [2]] [[[2, 1], [2]], [[25, 1], [2]]]
```